# Splunk extract all values from array field

Tags: logging, charts, splunk, data-extraction

I have log entries containing counts per country in format:

```
Map(USA -> 1234, CAN -> 5678, GBR -> 9012, FRA -> 3456)
Map(USA -> 1238, CAN -> 5692, GBR -> 9024, FRA -> 3478)
...
```

I want to make a timechart in Splunk with one series per country.

This is what I tried:

```
| rex "Map\((?<countries>([A-Z]+\ ->\ \d+(,\ )?)*)\)" | rex field=countries max_match=50 "(?<countries>[A-Z]+\ ->\ \d+)(,\ )?" | table _time countries
```

That works great and gives us two columns:

1. time
2. counts per country - array of entries in format "USA -> 1234"

Then I tried to create a timechart, I replaced:

```
| table _time countries
```

with:

```
| rex field=countries (?<country>[A-Z]+)\ ->\ (?<count>\d+) | timechart count by country limit=0
```

But the result is that all counts are taken from the last country in the list.

How can I extract the counts per country for all items in array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `rex`s should be sufficient to extract the country names and counts

```
| makeresults 
| eval m="Map(USA -> 1234, CAN -> 5678, GBR -> 9012, FRA -> 3456)"
| rex field=m max_match=0 "(?<cc>\w+\s+->\s+\d+)"
| mvexpand  cc
| rex field=cc "(?<country>\w+) -> (?<count>\d+)"
| fields country, count
| eval {country}=count
| fields - country, count
```

Comment: And how can I create a timechart from the extracted data?

Comment: `eval {country}=count` means that there are new fields "USA", "CAN", ... but how can I add them all as arguments to the `timechart` command?

Comment: remove the last 2 lines (eval {country}=count and | fields...) and then do a timechart sum(count) by country. You may need to change around sum with first or latest depending on your data